# Multipart file maximum size configuration in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, multipart

My application server is Tomcat and I need is to upload files (large size)  to my application. The body size of `POST` requests is really long like 15 MB or more.

Is there any type of configuration or code I can set to overcome this problem?

Please keep in mind that this is `multipart` request with file upload

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you state what the problem is? Is it that your file is bigger than 15MB and you are limited to that?

Comment: you're using spring or spring boot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat 7 and and above has a configuration called `maxSwallowSize` that specify number of bytes for an upload with a default value of 2MB. If your application is configured to accept bigger file, for example with a MultipartResolver in Spring,  Tomcat will reject the request.

Because you can configure file size in your application, my advice is to disable `maxShallowSize` in `{TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/server.xml` using value `-1` and then work only with size configured in your application

as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
            maxSwallowSize="-1"/>
```

You can find a detailed description [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded) (with spring framerwork)

Comment: `maxSwallowSize` doesn't seem to be the max upload size.
_The maximum number of request body bytes (excluding transfer encoding overhead) that will be swallowed by Tomcat for an aborted upload._

Answer (score 1):

**1. First configure max file upload in Spring ( override default value 1MB)**

form ***spring mvc*** create  `bean` :

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
     CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
     resolver.setMaxUploadSize(15728640);
     resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(15728640);
     return resolver;
}
```

for ***spring boot*** : add in `application.properties`

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=15MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=15MB
```

**2. Second thing configure your tomcat :**

locate your server xml tomcat file  `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`

then chnage your connector as below by example :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="8443"
  maxSwallowSize = "-1"/>
```